# Can a Power Set be a Subset or Element of its Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As in can $P(S)$ be an element of $S$?

Comment: And as to the first question, if $P(S)$ were a subset of $S$, then inclusion would give an injection $P(S)\to S$, contradicting Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Yes, it does thanks a lot I've been trying to find a question like that for an hour now so thanks a mil. @HanulJeon you too Elliot

Comment: Not really sure I can accept a comment as an answer to a question though. Can I? 

EDIT: I kinda can it seems